# Socket EADDRINUSE Error

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to set up a working nodeJS socket.io server with express. However, I keep returning this error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::80
```

I have tried other solutions on this site which told me to search for and kill a process that is already running, but the `grep` commands return no running process. I can only assume the error is with my setup code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {path: '/folder/socket.io'}).listen(server);
app.get("/folder/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/folder/client/index.html");
});
app.use("/folder/client", express.static(__dirname + "/folder/client"));
app.listen(80);
```

Note that I specify the path `folder` because I want node to run on a subdirectory instead of the main path `/`. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
server.listen(80);
```

instead of

```
app.listen(80);
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

What I do on my cloud instances is I redirect port 80 to port 3000 with this command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Comment: I have just run this command and it has redirected all port 80 connections to port 3000 on my webserver, which is problematic because I have other projects running on my server which all use port 80. I am wondering if there is a way to reverse this?